# Sequelize: Create instance with existing association

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Trying to get sequelize to return the newly created object with an existing association. My goal is to create a new user with an association to an existing organisation and return both.

*in* ***user.model.js:***

```
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
    },
  });
  User.associate = (models) => {
    User.belongsTo(models.Organisation, {
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'organisationId',
        field: 'organisation_id',
      },
    });
  };
  return User;
};
```

*in* ***organisation.model.js:***

```
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Organisation = sequelize.define('organisation', {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
    },
  });
  return Organisation;
};
```

---

**SUCCEEDS: Getting an existing user**

I'm able to retrieve an existing user and its organisation using the `include` option for the query.

```
const user = models.User.findOne({
  where: {
    email: 'existing@user.com',
  },
  include: [
    { model: models.Organisation, attributes: ['name'] },
  ],
});
```

**FAILS: Creating a new user**

Instance is inserted but query fails to return organisation attributes.

```
const user = models.User.create({
  email: 'new@user.com',
  organisationId: 'existing-organisation-id'
}, {
  include: [
    { model: models.Organisation, attributes: ['name'] },
  ],
});
```

**SUCCEEDS: Creating a new user and querying it**

Instance is inserted and then using another query retrieved with organisation data. The problem is that it takes two queries to the database. It should only take one,

```
models.User.create({
  email: 'new@user.com',
  organisationId: 'existing-organisation-id'
}).then(() => {
  models.User.findOne({
    where: {
      email: 'new@user.com',
    },
    include: [
      { model: models.Organisation, attributes: ['name'] },
    ],
  });
});
```

I've been reading through the docs thoroughly but I think I must have missed something. The database I'm connecting to is **PostgreSQL**. Would really appreciate someone to point me in the right direction.

Comment: Are you using Postgresql?

Comment: Yes, that might be worth noting!

Comment: @nomadoda Did you found any solution?

Comment: Thiis same on Github: [Eager loading associations when calling create() or save()](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3807)

Comment: I'm having the same problem lol.

Answer (score 2):

I think that is not yet supported yet :

> options.include   : an array of include options - **Used to build
>   prefetched/included model instances**.

you can use include to create a associated data at same time , but you can't just fetch it like that

But shorter way of doing is :

```
models.User.create({
  email: 'new@user.com',
  organisationId: 'existing-organisation-id'
}).then((user) => {
    user.getOrganisation().then(org => {
        console.log(user,org); // <------ Check the console
    });
});
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately, I only get the `id`, `email` and `organisationId` fields returned when promise resolves.

Comment: @nomadoda , remove attributes from include and try again.

Comment: Hm no, sorry, doesn't seem to affect the outcome.

Comment: I have also tried `include: [models.Organisation]` to no avail

Comment: Thanks, that works fine! I'm not sure I understand the documentation you provided - does it mean that it definitely is not supported yet or?

Comment: @Vivek Doshi Did you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

One thing i caught is that you are using `organisation_id` in the user model relationship but didn't define it in the model. Sequelize will automatically create an `id` field for models that don't have PK defined. As far as the field name for it, i don't know how your config is setup to where if it may prefix it or leave it as `id`.

When i define relationships, i specify an `alias` using the `as` options. I also specify the relationship between both models. Here is how i would do it:

```js
Organisation.hasMany(User, {
  as: 'members',
  foreignKey: '<FK field on User model>',
  sourceKey: '<PK field on Organisation model>' 
});

User.belongsTo(Organisation, {
  as: 'organisation',
  foreignKey: '<FK field on User model>',
  targetKey: '<PK field on Organisation model>'
});
```

When a model `hasOne`/`hasMany` other model(s), the options object needs the `sourceKey` prop (the key field of the parent model, usually the PK); when a model `belongsTo` another model, the options object needs the `targetKey` prop (same as the sourceKey). The targetKey and sourceKey just specifies the relationship: which model is the child or parent of the other.

So in your case, i would do it like this:

```js
Organisation.hasMany(User, {
  as: 'members',
  foreignKey: 'organisation_id',
  name: 'organisationId',
  sourceKey: 'id' // assuming PK of Organisation is id
});

User.belongsTo(Organisation, {
  as: 'organisation',
  foreignKey: 'organisation_id', // assuming PK of Organisation is id
  name: 'organisationId',
  targetKey: 'id'
});
```

So now doing this should work:

```js
const user = models.User.create({
  email: 'new@user.com',
  organisationId: 'existing-organisation-id'
}, {
  include: [
    { association: models.Organisation, as: 'organisation', attributes: ['name'] },
  ],
});
```

i was following along this page when i started learning it - https://sequelize.org/master/manual/creating-with-associations.html